# Equation with slider value not working

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uislider

I'm trying to make an equation (in x-code) where a sliders value is suppose to be divided by 100 and then multiplied with a textfields value (which is input by the user). The result is supposed to be displayed in another text-field. 
my .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *counter;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberfield1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberfield2
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)changeLabel;
```

my .m file:

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel {
    _counter.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%1.f",_slider.value];
}

- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    float x = [_counter.text floatValue];
    float y = 100;
    float calc_result = x / y;
    float  calc_result2 = calc_result * _numberfield2; // (Invalid operand to binary expression ('float' and 'UITextField*'))
    self.numberfield2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", calc_result2];
}
```

What have I done wrong to get the error in () and what do I need to do fix it? Is there anyother flaws? If so how should I go about it?
Thanks in beforehand!

Comment: _numberfield2 seems like it is still a textfield. you need to convert its value to a float like you did with the slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    float x = [_counter.text floatValue];
    float y = 100;
    float calc_result = x / y;
    float numberField2Float = [_numberfield2.text floatValue]; //converts the string in the text field to a float
    float  calc_result2 = calc_result * numberField2Float;
    self.numberfield2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", calc_result2];
}
```